# BlackBerry - Reminder and SMS feature implementation

Tags: blackberry, sms, notifications

I am developing on BlackBerry 4.7 Storm device.

Reminder:

My application will allow user to enter data and set Date&Time to remind the notes. Can someone please suggest me how do i handle "reminder with some small description" at that particular Date&Time? What API or code should i use to handle reminder alarm?
I also want to add recurrence in this reminder, so that it will remind based on the available recurrence. Does recurrence and reminder API supported in BB?

It should do the following features:
1. Remind Birthday whenever it occurs(i am stroring that particular user DateOfBirth in my app persistent). It can show in alert or dialog with a smal description message. Reminder alert should be able to show even my app is not launched(opened).

2. Reminder should handle recurrence. If there is a recurrence enabled for that particular DateOfBirth reminder, then reminder alarm should be able to handle recurrence feature.

SMS:

If i want to develop my application, which will be able to send SMS with predefined text automatically in the background to the particular number, how to do that? Is it possible, (or) my app will allow user to click "Send" kind of button which will take user to built-in SMS app and allow to send?

Please give me some link (or) sample source to have a look?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Alert](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Alert.html) and [Dialog](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/Dialog.html) notifications for reminder.
Yes, it's possible to open sms application, see this article:
[Sending and receiving GSM SMS on Blackberry using RIM APIs](http://myhowto.org/java/j2me/22-sending-and-receiving-gsm-sms-on-blackberry-using-rim-apis/)

**UPDATE**
I don't know about reminders API in BlackBerry.
To show reminder without having your app running, you can try [PushRegistry](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/io/PushRegistry.html) class, although you'll have to create some MIDlet to show this reminder message:
[BlackBerry PushRegistry How-To](http://bittyjava.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/blackberry-pushregistry-how-to/)
[BB KB How To - Register a MIDlet with the PushRegistry](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800429/How_To_-_Register_a_MIDlet_with_the_PushRegistry.html?nodeid=817112&vernum=0)
[BB KB How To - Create an auto-start MIDlet using the PushRegistry](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800429/How_To_-_Create_an_auto-start_MIDlet_using_the_PushRegistry.html?nodeid=817209&vernum=0)
[BB KB How To - Create an auto-start MIDlet](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800660/How_To_-_Create_an_auto-start_MIDlet.html?nodeid=1408081&vernum=0)
[Using PushRegistry with SMS Communication](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/site/global/techsupport/tipstrickscode/java/p_tips_java_1201.jsp)

Comment: May i know how do i handle reminder? I want to show a reminder alert/dialog with a small description message when the particular B'day date arrives. It should be able to show reminder alert even when my app is not actively running.

Comment: I also want to add recurrence in this reminder, so that it will remind based on the available recurrence. Does recurrence and reminder API supported in BB? I don't want to use built-in calendar reminder. I think, there is a reminder alarm does this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I've understood your question well but here is answer according to what I've got.
You can use J2ME PIMs library which is personal information management system BB also implements PIM in its API. It is up to you which you want to use. BB deals with three stuff.
ToDO list, Event(Calander) and contacts. From this API you can attach a listener or anything to it.
Just google PIM api JME and Blackberry you will found thousands of examples