# how to integrate alarm in a rimlet or blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry, notifications, alarm

i am developing an application for blackberry i want alarm to ring on a specific date please help me out how to do it.

Comment: Please post the code you have already written: people do not generally like to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a short tips:

- Write background application to make alarm and UI application to configure things

**UPDATE**
Just extand you application class from [Application](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html) instead of [UiApplication](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiApplication.html)
See examples:
[BlackBerry background applications on StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blackberry+background-application)

Also, in Eclipse, in Project Properties->BlackBerry Project Properties->Application you can set process to be **system module** (hide app icon on device), as well to be **start-up**.

- Save configuration to Persistent Store
  [Blackberry - application settings save/load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476994/blackberry-application-settings-save-load)
- Use different types of notification (from Dialog to Alarm)
  [Blackberry - How to use notification icon in statusbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465224/blackberry-how-to-use-notification-icon-in-statusbar)
  [Notification Service for Blackberry OS 4.5 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465259/notification-service-for-blackberry-os-4-5-application)
  [Add a notification icon at the status bar in BlackBerry JDE 4.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845308/blackberry-reminder-and-sms-feature-implementation)
  [BlackBerry - Reminder and SMS feature implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845308/blackberry-reminder-and-sms-feature-implementation)

Comment: Please guide me how to write background app i have been searching to do it using eclipse. any short example will do the magic please help me